# azure durable function vscode local debug looking for DurableTask.dll in the wrong location and throwing an error

Tags: azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

When running azure durable functions locally on a windows nodejs install, I am getting this error when I run func start at the terminal:

> System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load file or assembly C:\Users\Admin\.azure-functions-core-tools\Functions\ExtensionBundles\Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle\3.3.0\bin_v3\linux-x64\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask.dll. Format of the executable (.exe) or library (.dll) is invalid.

I have followed the provided steps and used the following command to install extensions.csproj and the associated bin directory in my vscode functions project has the correct Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask.dll

> func extensions install -p Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask -v 1.8.3

So how can I configure my local functions setup to look for the DLL in my current projects bin folder than looking elsewhere as the error shows?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the issue by following this [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-create-first-csharp?pivots=code-editor-vscode)

1. Open VS Code > Azure Functions Extension > Create New Project > Selected the Stack (Azure Functions v3 - .Net Core 3.1 - C# - Durable Function Template).
2. By default, the version of `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask` is 2.5.1.

[image]

3. Executed the function locally and the output is:

[image]

4. Changed the `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask` version to 3.3.0 by using this .Net Core CLI Command:

`dotnet add package Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask --version 3.3.0`

[image]

- After changing the version to 3.3.0 and executing again, as it is saying that it's not a suitable version for azure functions v3 but the appropriate package version for `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask` (4.0.1) installing itself to run and executed successfully.
- According to this [Microsoft Documentation of Azure Functions Binding Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-register#extension-bundles), to add the extension bundles for `.csproj` using VS Code is through the .NET CLI Command but not required to add the extension bundles in `host.json`.
- Please check the compatibility version of WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask to CsProj from this [nuget Site](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask).

Comment: thanks for a detailed reply but I am working on a Javascript / NodeJS functions app. Please check the following link regarding the folder structure for a Javascript functions app, it also includes extensions.csproj and a bin folder with the right DurableTask.dll 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=v2#folder-structure

Comment: <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
 <WarningsAsErrors></WarningsAsErrors>
 <DefaultItemExcludes>**</DefaultItemExcludes>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask" Version="1.8.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator" Version="1.1.3" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>